# Is there a way to set my h1 to go on top of the paragraph because I've used display flex to set them vertically

Tags: html, css, web, text

As you can see I've used the display flex to vertically align my items, but I want the h1 to go on top of the paragraph.
[In the image you can see how the text are aligned in center.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHj02.png

```css
section{
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      scroll-snap-align: start;
  }



.one{
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<section id="about" class="one">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quo accusamus dolor, commodi repudiandae animi esse delectus ipsa <br>magni sed at expedita sint, beatae nulla? Adipisci quasi sint earum quo illo facere voluptatibus, praesentium est <br>neque tempore vitae quas aliquid molestias sit et ut, blanditiis <br>necessitatibus labore ducimus asperiores obcaecati!</p>
             <img src="./img/undraw_New_message_re_fp03.png" alt="img">
           </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the styling `flex-direction: column;` to your section css selector like so:

```css
section{
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* color: white; */
      scroll-snap-align: start;
  }



.one{
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<section id="about" class="one">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quo accusamus dolor, commodi repudiandae animi esse delectus ipsa <br>magni sed at expedita sint, beatae nulla? Adipisci quasi sint earum quo illo facere voluptatibus, praesentium est <br>neque tempore vitae quas aliquid molestias sit et ut, blanditiis <br>necessitatibus labore ducimus asperiores obcaecati!</p>
             <img src="./img/undraw_New_message_re_fp03.png" alt="img">
           </section>
```